# Binding a nested Collection to listview Columns

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, mvvm

I have a Object like this:

```cs
public class DummyVm {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<int> DummyList { get; set; }
}
```

and create a Collection to bind it to the view

```cs
public List<DummyVm> VmList { get; set; } = new List<DummyVm>()  { 
    new DummyVm() { Name = "test1", DummyList = new List<int>() { 5, 6 } }, 
    new DummyVm() { Name = "test2", DummyList = new List<int>() { 1, 2 } } 
};
```

how can i bind each element of the DummyList-Property to an own column?

In the End, my result shoud be a grid with 3 colums and 2 rows:

```
test1 | 5 | 6
test2 | 1 | 1
```

i am using mvvm

Comment: What have you tried so far? And how should this look if the `DummyList`'s have different lengths?

Comment: i tried to bind the List just like the "name" property and hoped that the listview would generate a column für each Property in the DummyList. but nope :)

Answer (score 0):

If VmList is declared in MainWindow.xaml.cs, add this to your MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="DummyVmTemplate">

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

            <Label FontSize="14" Content="{Binding Name}" />
            <Label Margin="20,0,0,0" Content="{Binding DummyList[0]}" />
            <Label Margin="20,0,0,0" Content="{Binding DummyList[1]}" />

        </StackPanel>
        
    </DataTemplate>
    
</Window.Resources>
```

Inside the `<Grid>` in MainWindow.xaml add:

```
<ListView x:Name="DummyListView"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DummyVmTemplate}" />
```

Then in the MainWindow.xaml.cs constructor add:

```
    Loaded += OnLoaded;
```

The OnLoaded() implementation should look like this:

```
    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DummyListView.ItemsSource = VmList;
    }
```